# Using std::make_unique with custom deleter on a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

Let's say I have a class called `Derived`, which inherits from a class called `Base`. `Base` is special - though it may be created using new, it has to be destructed through a custom deleter.

I would like to have the `Base` in an `unique_ptr` along with the custom deleter called `BaseDeleter`. This also allows me to have other classes that derive from `Base` assigned to it. And for the sake of exception-safety and consistency I'd like to use `std::make_unique` to assing my `unique_ptr`.

I created a small snippet that demonstrates what I want:

```
#include <memory>

class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

struct BaseDeleter
{
    void operator()(Base* base)
    {
        // Perform some special deleting
    }
};

class Big
{
public:
    Big()
    {
        //pointer.reset(new Derived()); // This works!
        pointer = std::make_unique<Derived, BaseDeleter>(); // But this doesn't...
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base, BaseDeleter> pointer;
};

int main()
{
    Big clazz;
}
```

Unfortunately this fails to compile on both Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and gcc-5.1. ([ideone](https://ideone.com/3DULYC))
Why does this not work? How could one use `std::make_unique` to assign such a `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is (one of) the signature(s) of `make_unique`, the one that I guess you expect to be used:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );
```

Where `T` is the type of the object you want to create, `Args...` are the types of the arguments you are to forward to the constructor.

As you can see, you cannot indicate a custom deleter with the `make_*` helper functions for smart pointers (neither with `make_unique`, nor with `make_shared`).

You have to explicitly construct your pointer as it follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<T, D> ptr{new T{)};
```

If the deleter is not default constructible, you can do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T, D> ptr{new T{}, d};
```

Where `d` is an instance of the deleter.

Answer (score 4):

Make unique does not work with custom deleters.  Write your own or do not use it.

This has nothing to do with the base/derived complication in your question, which is a red herring.